# PgAdmin4 server list stuck infinitely loading but never loads my servers

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgadmin

I have looked everywhere for this issue and all I can see is connection related issues. I have no problem loading PgAdmin4 but the issue comes after I input my password and click the drop down server list on the left side. It will just never stop loading and servers never show up. I have tried restarting the windows server, restarting the Postgres server agent and nothing fixes it. Never had or heard of this issue.

[image]

If anyone has suggestions that would be great. I will try reinstalling PgAdmin but if that doesn't work I am out of options.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing some more troubleshooting, deleted old v6 from my server and made sure I was running v7 and it seemed to fix my issue. So if anyone runs into the same issue this may be your problem.